# Using @JsonIgnore on my getter is making it so that my variable doesn't show up in the POST model schema either

Tags: swagger

I have the following:

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@JsonProperty
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

What I'd like is for the swagger UI to show the password field on my POST function still as I am only hiding it from the GET call.

Right now when I click on "Model Schema" in my swagger UI I see the following:

{

"email": "",

"nickname": "",

"dateOfBirth": "java.util.Date"

}

Notice the password field is missing. It shows the JSON response for the expected return object.

Putting @JsonIgnore on my setters and @JsonProperty on my getters works as expected. However putting @JsonIgnore on my getter and @JsonProperty on my setter I'd expect the variable to show up in the POST's model schema. As the password field is not being shown currently, someone looking at my API would have no idea that a password is expected.

Is there a way to solve this? Right now the model schema listed in my api for the post calls does not line up with what is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can't do that with a single model. With Swagger, you need to have two separate models to describe a different input and output model (even if you use a single class, each needs to have its own name). It can be made easier using model composition, but still requires two separate models.

Swagger-core will *not* translate that definition to two separate models and will assume the worst-case scenario where it is hidden. If you wish to change that behavior, I'd suggest opening a ticket on the project.